# Swap order of arguments to "then" with Bluebird / NodeJS Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, fs

I have a function which asynchronously grabs a value from a server:

```
var request = require('request');
Promise.promisifyAll(request);
function getValue(){
    return request.getAsync('http://www.google.com')
        .then(function(resp){ return resp.body; })
        .catch(function(err){ thow err; });
}
```

I want to take this value and dump it to a file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
Promise.promisifyAll(fs);
getValue().then(fs.writeFileAsync, "file.html");
```

The problem is that `fs.writeFileAsync` expects parameter one to be the file and parameter two to be the data, but `getValue()` returns the data. This is error'ing out saying:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open '<html....'
    at Error (native)
```

I could circumvent this for now by writing a helper function to swap the parameters:

```
function myWriteFile(data, fileName) {
    return fs.writeFileAsync(fileName, data);
}
```

Although if it's possible to fix this without writing a helper function that would be preferred, as I expect a lot of similar issues to arise and don't want to clutter my code with 50 helper functions. I also feel like passing data to `writeFile` from a promise is probably a very common use case.

Comment: `then(fs.writeFileAsync, "file.html")` does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: You don't pass function arguments directly to `.then()` so your idea here is entirely flawed here.  `.then()` accepts one or two function references, that's all it accepts.  The first function reference is the resolve handler, the second is the reject handler.

Comment: I'm new to using promises (first project to ever use them), and this makes sense, although it doesn't explain an earlier bug that I was able to fix by passing a parameter. I have a tilde-expansion helper function which returns a promise. I then had the code `tilde(fileName).then(fs.readFileAsync).then(function(data){console.log(data);})` -- this returned a buffer, not a string. I replaced it with `tilde(fileName).then(fs.readFileAsync, "utf8").then(function(data){console.log(data);})` and it returned a string

Comment: Did some git log research and it looks like I used to have `fs.readFileAsync(fileName, "utf8")`, but when I added the tilde-expansion library I converted it improperly to `tilde(fileName).then(fs.readFileAsync, "utf8")`. I tested and it is returning a buffer again and not a string. The only reason my code didn't break is because the code afterwards apparently supports buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to the `.then()` function is an error callback, not a parameter.  Your code doesn't work at all.

Instead, you can use `.bind` to pre-bind a parameter:

```
getValue().then(fs.writeFileAsync.bind(null, "file.html"));
```

Note that the first parameter to `.bind()` is the `this` parameter, which doesn't matter.