# How to persist data through promise chain in NodeJS (Bluebird)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Follow-up to [Swap order of arguments to "then" with Bluebird / NodeJS Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486499/swap-order-of-arguments-to-then-with-bluebird-nodejs-promises) (the posted answer worked, but immediately revealed a new issue)

This is the first time I've ever used promises in NodeJS so I apologize if some conventions are poorly adhered to or the code is sloppy. I'm trying to aggregate data from multiple APIs, put it in a database, then compute some statistics based on similarities and differences in the data. As a starting point I'm trying to get an API token for a single one of the APIs.

Here is my full code:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
Promise.promisifyAll(fs);
Promise.promisifyAll(request);

// tilde-expansion doesn't follow the callback(err, data) convention
var tilde = function(str) {
    var _tilde = require('tilde-expansion');
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        try {
            _tilde(str, resolve);
        } catch(e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}

var getToken = function() {
    return request.getAsync(process.env.token_url, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "applications/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        form: {
            client_id: process.env.client_id,
            client_secret: process.env.client_secret,
            grant_type: "client_credentials"
        }
    })
        .then(function(resp) { return resp.body; });
}

var tokenFile = tilde(process.env.token_file)
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Error parsing path to file... can not recover");
    });

var token = tokenFile
    .then(fs.readFileAsync) //, "utf8")
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log("Token (from file): " + data);
        return data;
    })
    .then(JSON.parse)
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Error reading token from file... getting a new one");
        return getToken()
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log("Token (from API): " + data);
                return data;
            })
            .then(JSON.stringify)
            .then(fs.writeFileAsync.bind(null, tokenFile.value()));
    });

token.then(function(data) {
    console.log("Token (from anywhere): " + token.value);
});
```

This code is currently logging:

```
Token: undefined
```

if I fall back to the API. Assuming I did my promise stuff correctly (`.catch()` can return a promise, right?) then I would assume the issue is occurring because `fs.writeFileAsync` returns void.

I would like to append a `.return()` on the end of this promise, but how would I gain access to the return value of `getToken()`? I tried the following:

```
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Error reading token from file... getting a new one");
        var token = "nope";
        return getToken()
            .then(function(data) {
                console.log("Token (from API): " + data);
                token = data;
                return data;
            })
            .then(JSON.stringify)
            .then(fs.writeFileAsync.bind(null, tokenFile.value()))
            .return(token);
    });
```

However this logs "nope".

Comment: What is `.return()`?

Comment: It's a bluebird convenience method, abbreviation for `.then(function(value) {
   return value;
});`

Comment: You shouldn't promisify `request` instead you should be using [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise). Its built using Bluebird promises

Comment: @peteb While I like the idea of a library which already does for me exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, if `request` is updated then how long will I have to wait for the update to propagate to `request-promise`? I get really wary of long dependency chains - I'd rather know I have the latest and greatest at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the weekend I continued my research on promises and upon making a pivotal realization I was able to develop the solution to this. Posting here both the realization and the solution:

### The Realization

Promises were invented so that asynchronous code could be used in a synchronous manner. Consider the following:

```
var data = processData(JSON.parse(readFile(getFileName())));
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
var filename = getFileName();
var fileData = readFile(filename);
var parsedData = JSON.parse(fileData);
var data = processData(parsedData);
```

If any one of these functions is asynchronous then it breaks, because the value isn't ready on time. So for those asynchronous bits we used to use callbacks:

```
var filename = getFileName();
var data = null;
readFile(filename, function(fileData){
    data = processData(JSON.parse(fileData));
});
```

This is not only ugly, but breaks a lot of things like stack traces, try/catch blocks, etc.

The **Promise pattern** fixed this, letting you say:

```
var filename = getFileName();
var fileData = filename.then(readFile);
var parsedData = fileData.then(JSON.parse);
var data = parsedData.then(processData);
```

This code works regardless of whether these functions are synchronous or asynchronous, and there are zero callbacks. It's actually all *synchronous* code, but instead of passing *values* around, we pass *promises* around.

The led me to the realization that: *for every bit of code that can be written with promises, there is a synchronous corollary*

### The solution

Realizing this, I tried to consider my code if all of the functions were synchronous:

```
try {
    var tokenFile = tilde(process.env.token_file)
} catch(err) {
    throw new Error("Error parsing path to file... can not recover");
}

var token = null;
try {
    token = JSON.parse(readFile(tokenFile));
} catch(err) {
    token = getToken();
    writeFile(tokenFile, JSON.stringify(token));
}

console.log("Token: " + token.value);
```

After framing it like this, the promise version follows logically:

```
var tokenFile = tilde(process.env.token_file)
    .catch(function(err) {
        throw new Error("Error parsing path to file... can not recover");
    });

var token = tokenFile
    .then(readFile)
    .then(JSON.parse)
    .catch(function(err) {
        var _token = getToken();
        _token
            .then(JSON.stringify)
            .then(writeFile.bind(null, tokenFile.value));
        return _token;
    });
```